# Python - getting duration of a video with ffprobe

Tags: python, windows, cmd, ffprobe

I am new in Python and I am trying to get the duration (in seconds) of a file video by using *ffprobe*. 
Calling the following instruction

```
ffprobe -i video.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

on the CMD, I get the right result in seconds but if I call the same instruction in python by using:

```
import subprocess
duration = subprocess.call(['ffprobe', '-i', 'video.mp4', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv="p=0"'])
print duration
```

it returns 1.
Is there a way to get the right result also through Python?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with the double quote argument `p=0` , format it using `%`, also i changed `subprocess.call` to `subprocess.check_output` to store output of the command in a  string :

```
import subprocess
duration = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-i', 'video.mp4', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=%s' % ("p=0")])
print(duration)
```

Output:

```
8.824000
```

or you can otherwise do this:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", "video.mp4"],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
for x in result.stdout.readlines():
      if "Duration" in x:
          print(x[12:23])
          break
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from subprocess import check_output

file_name = "movie.mp4"

#For Windows
a = str(check_output('ffprobe -i  "'+file_name+'" 2>&1 |findstr "Duration"',shell=True)) 

#For Linux
#a = str(check_output('ffprobe -i  "'+file_name+'" 2>&1 |grep "Duration"',shell=True)) 

a = a.split(",")[0].split("Duration:")[1].strip()

h, m, s = a.split(':')
duration = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)

print(duration)
```

Comment: A downvote is fine but do have the **courtesy** to explain why !
The code posted above is a **clear cut solution** to the question asked by the OP.

Comment: I don't know really, but suspect due to raw output parsing which usually not recommended if formatted output is available. Output strings are more frequent to change in future releases and also usually localized (l10n/i18n).