# ffprobe filter videos by duration, command prints but does not return duration

Tags: python, shell, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffprobe

I am attempting to use ffprobe to filter through videos by their duration. I was using:

```
vid_length = subprocess.call(f"ffprobe -i {local_vids_2[count]} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv='p=0'", shell = True)
print("VIDEO LENGTH IS:", vid_length, "FOR: ", count)
```

While I DO get the duration printed to my command prompt by the shell command, I noticed I DON'T get it returned as a variable like I need. Instead it's returning 0, so I get something like: `VIDEO URL IS: 100_scaled.mp4 FOR:  0 11.883000 VIDEO LENGTH IS: 0 FOR:  0` and  `VIDEO URL IS: 101_scaled.mp4 FOR:  1 56.171000 VIDEO LENGTH IS: 0 FOR:  1` etc.

I have also tried `vid_length = subprocess.call(f"ffprobe -i {local_vids_2[count]} -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv=%s % ('p=0')", shell = True)` based on what I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977472/python-getting-duration-of-a-video-with-ffprobe) but that hasn't worked either.

Is there a way I can get this command to return anything? Or do I need something else that will return the video length for coding purposes? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Subprocess allows catching the stdout (the printing). You can have it in byte form if you do something like :

```py
completedProcess = subprocess.run(myCommandHere, capture_output=True)
print(completedProcess.stdout)
data_as_str = completedProcess.stdout.decode()
```

Then you can parse the stdout for the data